# "... due to their not being citizens ." - is that a reasonable use of "their"

Tags: grammar

I wrote a sentence just now and after I'd pressed 'send' I began to wonder whether what I had written was correct.

The sentence read

> They were ineligible due to their not being citizens

An alternative - it seems to me - could be

> They were ineligible due to them not being citizens

but that sounds a little clunky.

Is there anything wrong withe the first one ?

Comment: "not being" is a gerund phrase, i.e. it acts as a noun

Comment: Yes, it is.  "Not being citizens" is a gerund phrase, which means it's a noun.  "Their" is a determiner that takes possession of that noun.  It is perfectly grammatical.  "Them not being citizens" is not grammatical.  The only other grammatical option is "they not being citizens."

Comment: I better re-write might be "They were ineligible because they are/were not citizens."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: "due to they not being citizens"? You can't mean that!

Comment: @TonyK. I agree with you; a nominative pronoun like "they" would be completely impossible as subject of a subordinate non-finite clause like " their/them not being citizens". Only genitive "their" and accusative "them" are possible.

Answer (score 1):

The gerund in this case is used in a possessive sense. 'Not being' belongs to them. So what you have written is correct.

There are some usages about which we should be careful. For example:

I hate him playing foot ball. This means that I hate him for playing foot ball. How he plays, does not matter.

I hate his playing foot ball. This means that I hate the manner in which he plays foot ball. My hatred is not about his playing foot ball. (This usage, however, is not possible in the sentence under consideration.)

For more details please see: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/gerunds.htm

Comment: "I hate his playing football" does NOT mean "I hate him ..." - it means I hate it when he plays football; or I hate the fact that he plays football.  Also "I hate his playing football." does NOT mean "I hate the manner in which he plays football" - it means exactly the same as the first sentence.

Comment: @TrevorD I agree.   If you wanted to talk about the **way** he plays football you could say "I hate his football playing".

Answer (score 1):

You are right.  Non-finite gerund-participle clauses as complement can take both genitive and non-genitive subjects - in the latter case accusative form only.

So it has to be:

*They were ineligible due to their/them not being citizens*.

Note that nominative pronouns as subjects of non-finite clauses are impossible, and hence * *... due to they not being citizens* would be completely ungrammatical.

In your example, the choice between genitive and non-genitive depends on style, the genitive being characteristic of fairly formal style.

Comment: +1 from me. I see your pet downvoter must still be following you around.

Answer (score 1):

Since gerunds act as nouns, it is only grammatical to deploy adjectives or adjectival determiners. My understanding is that **them** is a pronoun( third person plural object)...**they** is the subject form of **them**. A pronoun cannot qualify a noun, only an adjective can. That is why possessive adjectives like **my, your, his, their , our and its** should be preferred. Do you mind **my** coming...not **me** or **I** coming. **their not being citizens** sounds more  grammatical... them not being or they not being might just be informal colloquialism.